# java recursive linked list

Tags: java, recursion

```
     private Node<T> recremoveFirst (Node<T> list, T element)
     {

 if (list == null)
     return null;
 else if(list.next == element)
     return list.next;
 else{
     list.next = recremoveFirst(list.next, element);
     return list;
 }

 }//calling recursive method
     public void removeFirst(T element) {

    recremoveFirst(head, element);

 }
 int choice;
Element elem;//constructor public Element (String name, int no)

LinkedList<Element> list = new LinkedList<Element>();

String name;
int number;
case 1 :  // addFirst
      System.out.print("Type name and number: ");
      name = Cin.readString();
      number = Cin.readInt();
      list.addFirst(new Element(name,number));
      break;
    case 2 :  // addLast
      System.out.println("Enter name and number to add last element: ");
      name = Cin.readString();
      number = Cin.readInt();
      list.addLast(new Element(name, number));
      break;

 case 3 :  // removeFirst

        list.removeFirst(elem);
```

When I'm trying to test this recursive method it shows me an error near list.removeFirst(elem);
and gives only suggestion initialize it even though it is initialized(if press initialize sets it to null). So I wonder what's is that I'm doing wrong.
Error mssage: Multiple markers at this line
    - The local variable elem may not have been 
     initialized
    - The constructor Element(Element) is 
     undefined

Comment: You have initialized the list but its empty and you are trying to remove particular element

Comment: `if(list.elem == element)` <-- are you sure about this one?

Comment: supposed to be list.next

Comment: What you're doing wrong: you're not reading, nor posting the error message that the compiler produces and which indicates what the error is. And you're trying to work, and make us work with code that is very hard to read because it's not formatted correctly. Your IDE can format it using a single keyboard shortcut.

Comment: error message: Multiple markers at this line
 - The local variable elem may not have been 
  initialized
 - The constructor Element(Element) is 
  undefined

Comment: Just an observation, a recursive design like this will produce a stack overflow exception for large lists.  I just thought that it was interesting since it's the name of this site =D.

Comment: OK. So you're trying to call `removeFirst(elem)`, but you haven't initialized `elem` yet. That's what the error message tells you: *The local variable elem may not have been initialized*. Variables must be initialized before they can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
Element elem;
```

could be null when

```
list.removeFirst(elem);
```

is executed.

So it will be

```
Element elem = null;
```

(You need to initialize it to use it.)

Anyway, i'm pretty sure you want something like this:

```
list.addFirst(elem = new Element(name,number));
```

So it

```
list.removeFirst(elem);
```

will remove the item added recently.

Anyway, are you sure you don't want to use [**`removeFirstOccurrence`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirstOccurrence%28java.lang.Object%29) ? Because [`removeFirst`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#removeFirst%28%29) does a total different thing.

**removeFirstOccurrence**:

> Removes the first occurrence of the specified element in this list (when traversing the list from head to tail). If the list does not contain the element, it is unchanged.

Anyway the reason you get this error, is not related to the recursion

**Edit**:

Well, you don't need any edit to addFirst since removeFirst will remove the first item in the list.
You just need to change

```
removeFirst(elem);
```

to

```
removeFirst();
```

In this case, if you don't use it in other places, you don't need anymore `elem`.

Comment: I might, just don't really know what that is

Comment: You need to replace `list.removeFirst` with `list.removeFirstOccurrence(elem);` If you want to remove `elem` from the list.

Comment: Edited answer, you don't need to edit anything since addFirst/removeFirst will do it for you. But anyway, you need to remove the first arg from removeFirst and, if you don't need it anymore, remove elem variable.